# keytool can't find alias

Tags: ssl, alias, keytool

I've got a pfx certificate that I need to reference by alias. The problem is that keytool can't find that alias, even though it shows on the list.

```
keytool -list -keystore temp.pfx -storetype pkcs12
```

gives me this:

```
...
0c5fc7cef279ca390acd2d6bac9ffcf8_ba0cbbb3-323d-4394-8e76-47838adb2a9c, 08/03/2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
...
```

But whenever I try to use keytool to do anything with that alias (i.e., export, rename), it gives me an error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <0c5fc7cef279ca390acd2d6bac9ffcf8_ba0cbbb3-323d-4394-8e76-47838adb2a9c> does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that after inspecting the output of `keytool -list` on vim, I found a null character at the end of the alias (which doesn't get printed to the console). Once I added that to the command that references an alias, it worked:

```
keytool -keyclone -changealias -v -dest "new_alias" -new newpass -keystore temp.pfx -storetype pkcs12 -alias 0c5fc7cef279ca390acd2d6bac9ffcf8_ba0cbbb3-323d-4394-8e76-47838adb2a9c$'\x00'
```

Where the very end is what really matters: `$'\x00'` stands for null character in bash. Keep in mind that this is pretty shell-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

my case was similar to Andre, but the alias was

letsencryptisrgx1 [jdk]

so using alias "letsencryptisrgx1 [jdk]" it worked for me