# Fault alias name for keystore entry

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

Trying to get a certifiacate from given keystore. Problem is that the alias name contains a nul character. when looking into the output when calling:

```
keytool -export -alias "myAlias" -keystore "mystore" -storetype PKCS12 -file cert.cer
```

Redirected Output to txt file:

```
aliasFollwedByAUnknownCharacter , 12.09.2016, PrivateKeyEntry,...
```

Seeing that after aliasFollwedByAUnknownCharacter is a additional character. Opening With notepad++ shows NUL.

And because of this faulty naming the upper method cant find the alias myAlias in my keystore.

A highly related post from '13 [click me to forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301005/keytool-cant-find-alias)
Related

Is there any way to change the "unknown" alias (or some other fancy solution?)

/e forgot to mention that i tried following solutions:

`Control + Space`, `Alt +255`, `Space` And with `quotes`